# Condensation on HVAC, mold on joists/subfloor in basement

Tags: hvac, basement, mold

I have heavy condensation on the plenum and supply line near an exterior wall/window in my unfinished basement. I have mold and moisture on my subfloor and joists just in this 3 sections. I sealed up all of the major HVAC leaks there with mastic and HVAC tape, trying to dry out the subfloor before treating it for mold.

The humidity by that window is 70%, by the next window over it is 52%. I can't feel any warm air coming in around it? This section is a cantilever for our master.

[url=https://ibb.co/X5HkjL4][img]https://i.ibb.co/X5HkjL4/20200728-192355.jpg[/img][/url][image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SE, please take the tour so you can best know how to participate.   Also, I'm not sure of what you are asking.  Please EDIT your question to clarify your specific question.  And pictures also help a lot for us to help you.

Comment: Hello, I have been on DIY stack exchange for several months now. I am asking if anyone has any other ideas of what could be causing this? Air/humidity getting in through the cantilever? I am not seeing how to post a photo, even though I have here in the past?

Comment: I pulled the insulation out of the joist. I'm now seeing it looks like they didn't use a joist hangers on the right joist? Also the staples that they tried to use to attach the bottom plywood to the joists all missed causing a large sag/gap. I'm guessing this is probably the source of humidity and warm air coming in, that is mixing with the cold air from the AC right there, causing all of the condensation?

Comment: There are others here with far more expertise than I have on this. But for starters, I would think insulating the duct would dramatically cut down on condensation as well as improve A/C efficiency. Others, please chime in.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Now I'm worried about the lack of a joist hanger there and seeing that most of the staples missed the joist. Also getting rid of the mold, debating whether to try that on my own or hire a pro? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Wandering off-topic: where those staples missed, bang in a couple of nails or screws from below, call it good. Someone also got a little screw happy from above and put several along the edge of the plywood _between_ joists. At least the floor is screwed down. Back On topic, Please [edit] you post to put the actual question in the question - not everyone will find the question down here in the comments.

Comment: I agree with George insulating the duct will probably be your best option to reduce the condensation. Don’t sweat things like the hanger Working about things won’t help the issue . spray foam any cracks to seal things up. Reduce the area put some blocking in so the area with the pipe is reduced. 
If you want the best wrap with neoprene insulation we use that on the line sets to conserve energy and prevent ice buildup.